# PHP GD install issue

Tags: linux

When I try to insatll PHP GD on linux I get the below error

```
Error: Package: php-gd-7.3.33-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
           Requires: libgd.so.3()(64bit)
```

I tried to install lib gd with the command sudo yum install libgd.so.3

but I got error

```
rhel-7-server-supplementary-rpms                                                                                                      | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
No package libgd.so.3 available.
```

Can anyone please help on this ?

Full yum command

```
Loaded plugins: enabled_repos_upload, langpacks, package_upload, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
rhel-7-server-optional-rpms                                                                                                           | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-rh-common-rpms                                                                                                          | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-rpms                                                                                                                    | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-supplementary-rpms                                                                                                      | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:7.3.33-1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1 for package: php-gd-7.3.33-1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.3()(64bit) for package: php-gd-7.3.33-1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-gd-7.3.33-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
           Requires: libgd.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-gd-7.3.33-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
           Requires: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1
**********************************************************************
yum can be configured to try to resolve such errors by temporarily enabling
disabled repos and searching for missing dependencies.
To enable this functionality please set 'notify_only=0' in /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/search-disabled-repos.conf
**********************************************************************

Error: Package: php-gd-7.3.33-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
           Requires: libgd.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-gd-7.3.33-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
           Requires: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
Uploading Enabled Repositories Report
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, subscription-manager
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a proper repository configuration please follow the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions

It looks like the **remi-safe** repository is not enabled (it should, on default provided configuration)

```
# yum install php-gd

=================================================================================================================================
 Package                    Arch                      Version                                Repository                     Size
=================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 php-gd                     x86_64                    7.3.33-1.el7.remi                      remi-php73                     85 k
Installing for dependencies:
 gd-last                    x86_64                    2.3.3-2.el7.remi                       remi-safe                     138 k

Transaction Summary
=================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+1 Dependent package)

Total download size: 223 k
Installed size: 625 k
Is this ok [y/d/N]:
```

Comment: Hi, Remi-safe repository is enabled

Comment: So should be found by yum:
https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/safe/x86_64/repoview/gd-last.html

Comment: Also, post "full" yum output

Comment: I have edited the question and added  yum output

Comment: Sorry no idea... download the needed package from above link (workaround). Perhaps something wrong in your yum configuration.

Comment: Thanks I did the workaround and it worked fine